# Executing two functions as part of a foreach statement

Tags: php, foreach

This is more of a best practices question:

Say I want to execute two functions in a foreach statement (to combine the returns of these functions for use as a single element for the loop), would I combine them in the statement such as:

```
foreach(function1($data).function2($data) AS $key=>$value)
```

or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What `function1` and `function2` returns?

Comment: in this case, both are glpb functions returning the contents of a directory (list of filenames), i want to scan two directories and combine the two lists into one for the loop.

Comment: Maybe I got you wrong but `array_merge`? http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: Looks like that will do just fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If **function1** and **function2** return arrays then:

```
foreach(array_merge(function1($data),function2($data)) AS $key=>$value)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, arrays are concatenated with [`+`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) or [`array_merge()`](http://www.php.net/array-merge), the dot is only used for strings, so you would get the string "ArrayArray".

Second, for better readability and maintainability you should separate the function calls and the loop initialization:

```
$fileList = function1($data); 
$fileList += function2($data);
foreach($fileLists AS $key=>$value) {
}
```

Note that this does not make a difference in outcome or performance of the code, it just helps debugging and understanding (which is generally more important by the way).